# Using print(", ".join(my_array)) to extract individual strings and adding it to streamlit markdown. Instead of getting the string, I am getting NONE

Tags: python, pandas, markdown, nonetype, streamlit

I am using Streamlit to showcase some work that I have been doing on some data. So I have a dataframe named `total_home_wins` that contains the scores of the matches won by my team at home in the league. I am trying to find out the largest win won by my team. Kindly note that:

- `gd`: Goal Difference
- `FTHG`: Fulltime Home Goals

The following is my code to determine that:

```
biggest_gd_home = total_home_wins.loc[total_home_wins["gd"] == total_home_wins["gd"].max()]
biggest_win_home = biggest_gd_home.loc[biggest_gd_home["FTHG"] == biggest_gd_home["FTHG"].max()]
biggest_win_home_opponent = biggest_win_home.loc[:, "AwayTeam"].values[0]
```

And I was printing it on a page like so:

```
f'### Biggest victory at home against {biggest_win_home_opponent}'
st.write(biggest_win_home)
```

Previously I was not considering the fact that there could be more than one team with which my team won by the biggest margin. However, it turns out that there is a case where the both the `gd` and `FTHG` are exactly the same. No, problem - changed the code to the following:

```
biggest_win_home_opponent = list(biggest_win_home.loc[:, "AwayTeam"].values)
```

So now I have `biggest_win_home_opponent` as an array. If I leave the code as it is, it prints:

```
Biggest victory at home against ['Team X', 'Team Y']
```

I wanted it to appear without the brackets and the quotation marks, so I did the following:

```
'Biggest victory at home against' + print(", ".join(biggest_win_home_opponent))
```

This results in `NONE` instead of the team names. I tried replacing the `+` with `,` but to the same effect.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try modifying your f string code after having defined the list as you did:

```
f'### Biggest victory at home against {", ".join(biggest_win_home_opponent)}'
st.write(biggest_win_home)
```

As a prove of concept:

```
biggest_win_home_opponent = ['Team X', 'Team Y']
f'### Biggest victory at home against {", ".join(biggest_win_home_opponent)}'
```

Outputs this:

```
'### Biggest victory at home against Team X, Team Y'
```

Comment: My good sir/madam, you are the boss! 

I was so close! It did not occur to me to just ditch `print()` and bring it inside the f string.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Python [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are very powerful, it is a good idea to get familiar with them to write neater (and faster) code.